# Qt Save as File dialog show filename as untitled in Mac 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qfiledialog

In my application i want the Save as dialog as a sheet dialog ,so i make an instance of `QFileDialog` instead of using the static method `getSaveFileName`.

When i create the instance of `QFileDialog` i pass all the required parameters correctly, but still when the dialog is display only the first time correct file name is displayed,there after Qt only displays “Untitled” as the file name.Even though i am providing the correct file name.

I am using Qt 5.3. OS: Mac:10.9.

Has anybody faced this issue?

I already saw similar issue mentioned here : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36212 , but here again the static method is getting used.

I did some more testing by creating a project in Qt Creator (5.3.1 Clang 5.0 ( Apple ),64 bit ),this project just has `QPushButton` which on clicked displays the Save as dialog box.

The first time the output is correct:

[image]

Second time onwards the file name is always displayed as “Untitled”:

[image]

My code is quite straight forward:

```
#include “mainwindow.h”
#include “ui_mainwindow.h”
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{ 
   QPushButton *pButton = new QPushButton( “Save As..”, this ); 
   connect( pButton,SIGNAL),this,SLOT)); setCentralWidget( pButton );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::OnClicked()
{ 
   QFileDialog *pFile = new QFileDialog ( this, “TestApplication”, “BoomBoom”, “.jpg” ); 
   pFile->setAcceptMode( QFileDialog::AcceptSave ); 
   pFile->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal ); int statusCode = pFile->exec();
}
```

Comment: Does `pFile->selectFile("BoomBoom");` work?

Comment: @thuga No, it does not make a difference

Comment: Might be worth submitting a bug report. By the way, every time you click your button, you create a new instance of `QFileDialog`. This means you could have hundreds of `QFileDialog` instances laying around for no reason. Even though parent deletes its children, in cases like this it would be smart to delete the dialog when you don't need it anymore. Or just create one instance and have it as a member of your class.